# How to continue project from specific commit and fix HEAD detached issue?

Tags: git, version-control, head, git-detached-head

I checkouted specific commit from my project and continued from there, hoping that changes after that commit would be deleted, and that commit I checkouted would be new head. I commited new changes, but I can't push them. I'm still new to git.

What I have done is:

1. git checkout commit_hash
2. edited project
3. git commit -m "new changes"
4. git push -u origin master

I got:

```
To https://github.com/myusername/project.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/miloradsimic/ISA16.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

When I typed *git status* I got:

```
HEAD detached from 506f0ec
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I changed project hierarchy, in head commit, so I want to get it back on previous state. I dont want to merge it with head.

**I did it this way (easy way, not professional):**
I had in one folder project with changes, not positioned on head.
I downloaded head commit into new folder, and copied all files (except git files) from folder with my changes to this folder. Removed unnecessary files. Added all changes, commited and pushed.

Thanks, Milorad Simic

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When we checkout to a commit-hash we are **no longer on a branch** (`detached HEAD`).

> HEAD detached from 506f0ec

To solve it just create a new branch, do changes, do new Commits, Push to remote.

Checkout to a commit-hash.

```
$ git checkout <commit-hash>
```

You can do changes/commits here and create a new branch later before push to remote (your case here). But I prefer to create a new branch (say, `dev`) first.

```
$ git checkout -b dev
// do changes here

$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'message'
$ git push -u origin HEAD       # push to remote/dev
```

---

**Merge `dev` branch into `master` branch:**

You need to `merge dev branch` into `master` branch to get your new changes.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull origin dev      # pull 'dev' new changes into 'master', pull = fetch + merge

$ git push origin HEAD     # update origin/master
```

---

**Replace `master` branch with `dev` branch**

If you want to reset `master` with the changes of `dev` branch then replace `master` with `dev` branch.

```
$ git checkout dev
$ git branch -D master      # delete local master branch

$ git checkout -b master    # create new local/master branch with exactly 'dev's' history
$ git push -f origin HEAD   # force(-f) push to remote since git history is changed
```

**Note:** now `master` and `dev` have the same commits/changes.

Comment: I created new branch, but now I have 2 branches, master and dev. 
Can I as end result have only master branch with data from curent dev?

Comment: Yes, you can. I guess `master` is your `Default branch` so, don't delete `default` branch. Do you want to replace your `master` branch with `dev` branch now?

Comment: I have files that I want to delete from master. Could I go again to master head, and in next commit remove remote files that I don't need?

Comment: Yes you can it. `git checkout master`, delete the files, `git commit -am 'Delete unnecessary files'`, `git push origin HEAD`

Comment: But that would not apply my new changes. If I apply your commands, I would not have there my last changes. But if I position to master head, clear unnesesary files in next commit, hard copy my changes (files) to that repository and commit that again, it will do what I wanted. Bit that's not suposed to be done like that.

Comment: You need to `merge dev branch` into `master` branch to get your new changes. Updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can do `git reset --hard <commit-id>`

Then make your changes/commit.

Cheers